# The text formatting changes when I paste text from one document to another

Tags: microsoft-word

When I tried to copy data from one document to another document the formatting is changing. This is happening for some cases only, In some of the cases it is keeping as the source formatting.

Should I need to change any formats or headings or anything else to keep the all the data consistent in the current document when copied into another document? The changes has to be done in the current document.

Comment: What are your settings in Word when copying from another document or program?

Answer (score 1):

When you paste in the new document a small icon shows near the end of your text it is called **Paste Options** Click on it and read the options:

Keep Source Formatting
Match Destination Formatting
Keep text only

Choose **Keep Source Formatting** in your case to keep the same formatting as the copied document.

Comment: My document contains different kinds of titles. When I copied the titles from one document to another document the formatting is missing for the some titles only rest of the titles are copied as it in the source document. Can you tell me what behavior is changing the formatting for some title. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Like the response choose **keep source formatting**